# Run regexp in PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

Using QGIS version 2.18.11
I have an attribute table with a column of over 500K of records that has many missing spellings, abbreviations and erroneous characters that I need cleaned up on a regular basis. I can use regexp in the field calculator but can only run one expression at a time. I need to run approximately 150 expressions.
 
Like:

```
regexp_replace("DirtyNames" ,'([-\/~!@#$%^&*{}:"<>?|/.,;=_+]?)', '') and regexp_replace("DirtyNames" ,'TRL', 'TRAIL')
```

I’m thinking a Python script would likely be the easiest way to do this but don’t know the Python language. The table is “Local_Streets”. The field is “DirtyNames” and the regexp results would go to the “CleanedNames” field.

```
# Run_Regexp_Statements
####################################
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
_DIRTY_FIELD = 'DirtyNames'
_CLEAN_FIELD = 'CleanedNames'
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
# Create a field to store the results
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
        [QgsField(_CLEAN_FIELD, QVariant.String),
layer.updateFields()


# **WHAT NEEDS TO GO HERE to be able to run the regexp’s ?**
# regexp_replace("DirtyNames" ,'([-\/~!@#$%^&*{}:"<>?|/.,;=_+]?)', '')
# regexp_replace("DirtyNames" ,'TRL', 'TRAIL')


Layer.commitChanges()
print 'Processing complete.'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the re library.

```
import re
replaced = re.sub(r'([-\/~!@#$%^&*{}:"<>?|/.,;=_+]?)',r'replacementpattern',dirty_line))
```

More [info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: Can the following line be  : 
`replaced = re.sub('TRL','TRAIL',replaced)` (and so on) in your code ?

Comment: Thanks Ena2345 and gisnside for your replies. I get a invalid syntax error on both. I looked at the link provided by Ena but I'm not really following what I'm doing wrong.<br>

import re<br>
replaced = re.sub('TRL','TRAIL',r'replacementpattern',_DIRTY_FIELD)

Comment: Well the reason why it doesn't work is because it only works for 1 value at the time. So if you looped through the layer you could do it. But such operation should cost you O(n). I don't know how much such operations delay on QGIS so I cannot estimate the time taken.